Is my Stack Overflow question appropriate or not appropriate, and why?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79078923/what-are-the-tradeoffs-between-etl-and-a-java-based-jobscheduler

I know that the title may lead one to think that the question might be too broad, but it is finished with two specific questions. As I'm not getting comments, what I'm doing wrong?

It appears to be both asking for opinion and unfocused. You need to ask one question, not 2. And while you state in the question body that you are making the 2 questions more specific, each one appears to my eye to be quite broad. For example, "Does maintanability matter in this decision?" is extremely broad, no? Also, in the second question, "Are there as many ETL professionals avaiable as java?", are you asking about numbers of developers in this field? It really looks to be much more appropriate to ask this in a discussion forum, not a specific Q&A site.

As this is written, this seems more like a duplicate of Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?; comments are never required for any votes: up/down/closure/reopen/delete/etc. If you want constructive feedback on your question, then focusing on the downvotes, and the lack of comments, is not how to ask for it.

@ThomA: I look on this meta question more as, "is my [main] question appropriate or not appropriate, and why?", a valid question to ask on meta.

Yet the title is "Why is my question being downvoted with no comments?" @HovercraftFullOfEels , and the content of the question doesn't really detract from that. This is why I've made the comment, and suggested the OP change the "vibe" of the question, rather than reach straight for the close as dupe feature.

@HovercraftFullOfEels got it.. ty. I think you expressed much better what I meant on your comment. Im editing the title.

@GabrielMoretti: you're welcome. I have also added an image of your now-deleted [main] site question for those who do not have the reputation to be able to see it here.

'but it is finished with two specific questions' yeah but that is still one too many. Only one question per post please. As for the questions themselves, 'does maintainability matter' -> opinion-based; 'are there as many professionals' -> more a question about jobs/careers than about programming.

For the future, I would really recommend containing yourself and abstain from putting questions in a numbered list like that. Even if they're not really separate questions but part of one whole, you format it exactly so people will be triggered to read it like you're asking multiple questions and will reach for that unfocused close button with inappropriate haste. Don't dangle red herrings, people will bite. You put yourself at an immediate disadvantage if the question needs to be reopened because of it.

@Gimby yea.. I felt like I had triggered something, It was so fast! ty for the advice

The questions are completely inappropriate, and can be found thus from basic principles. Before you self-deleted the question, it had received two close votes: one as "opinion-based" and one as "needs more focus". In addition to these, I argue that what you are trying to ask is simply off topic for Stack Overflow.
Since it appears in this case that some assistance is needed in understanding how these reasons apply here:
Understanding topicality
Fundamentally, your question is about choosing between two different technologies: "ETL" and "a Java-based job scheduler". By itself, this distinction is incoherent: ETL describes an approach to the problem that a job scheduler could follow, and there are any number of possible job schedulers that are written in Java - many of which presumably take an ETL approach. But based on the details of the question, you appear to mean your company's existing "large-scale ETL solution", contrasted with a hypothetical new job scheduler to be written in Java.
This is off topic because it's not a question about software development but a question about software project management. Yes, theoretically you could end up with programmers writing some Java code. But Stack Overflow is for questions that could come from one of those programmers, that are about the code. It's not for questions from managers who have to make hiring or time allocation decisions.
Understanding focus
You say:

I know that the title may lead one to think that the question might be too broad, but it is finished with two specific questions.

That's not good enough, full stop. We expect one specific question, except insofar as answering one would naturally answer another (i.e. that they are really aspects of the same thing phrased differently, and there isn't a good way to disentangle them into separate questions).
Understanding objectivity
Stack Overflow is for questions that can be answered objectively. We can't make your mind up for you. We don't work for your company, so we have no way of quantifying the ways in which your existing ETL solution might or might not meet your needs; we have no way to know why you are specifically considering Java for the new solution; we can't predict how long it will take to implement anything; etc. etc. So it would be grossly irresponsible to try to give advice as an outsider.
Even with your attempt to distill your concerns into questions, you've missed the mark completely. We can't tell you whether "maintainability" "matters" for you, because we have no way to assess what maintenance concerns you would encounter in the future or how painful they would be for your company to deal with, or what it means for your company to consider something to "matter". We can't tell you about the number of "ETL professionals" available as compared to "Java professionals", first off because those terms aren't well defined and it isn't our job to say who should qualify as either (or both at once), nor what "available" means in the context of your company (do you care how many years of experience they have? Where they're located around the world? What their salary expectations are? How willing are you to headhunt someone already employed? Etc. etc.)
Pay attention to how much background context you're trying to give us on this company, and you'll understand why we have this policy. Even with all that information, nobody on the Internet would be in a good position to make a decision for you. They would only be in a position to discuss the idea and give opinions; but Stack Overflow (Q&A) is not a discussion forum.
The purpose here is explicitly to produce questions that can be of use to others. We disallow opinion-based, subjectively questions largely because they depend on individual factors, and thus inherently can't be useful to anyone but the OP. (There is a certain extent to which pros and cons could be meaningfully listed in the Q&A format, while allowing individual readers to weigh those factors individually; but that's something you'll find more on other Stack Exchange sites.)
